# How to modernize bank's legacy IT system?

Tags: architecture, refactoring, software-design, legacy, banking

What are some effective ways of modernizing legacy big IT system like bank's IT system?
Assume there are about 10-20 standalone legacy systems from several developer companies, some written on old JSP, many are based on stored procedures and several dbs has dblinks between them, entities like account and user are not standartized among systems.

Replacing or rewriting whole system is not the way to go, because people are using it and many parts are not properly documented. 
I want to learn some incremental steps to improve step by step, while system is being used, not by stopping.

Is there any kind of system bus like thing to integrate all old systems in some way, and develop microservices to replace some parts of old systems?

What are the ways to learn things like these?

Thanks.

*I am a software developer, want to become an architect, but don't know how.

Answer (score 3):

Very, Very carefully.

The problem is, often these systems are very transactional (being a bank and all), and very tightly coupled.

You should pick up one use-case at a time, and develop it from the front-end back.  Pick something like Bill Pay, build a new UI, and have it talk to the back-end system via whatever interfaces are available.  If no integration (API) interfaces are available, build them.

Once you have a UI built, carve off deeper use-cases, still maintaining the back-end for the actual data repository.  At some point (theoretically), you will need to decide you have all your use-cases covered, and you will rewrite the data-store.  Depending on the complexity, this could take years.  Some of the trickiest interfaces are admin-interfaces, not customer-facing ones, and they are things nobody thinks about until they need them.

Odds are, your big problem isn't even technical, it's the change management in moving all these groups to a new system.  The human/political impact of this kind of a change is very complicated, and would have to be a major focus of your senior leadership to make it be successful. People become accustom to an interface, and since it's old, it probably "just works", so it is likely not going to be taken kindly to having it be changed.  Especially since any new program is due to have bugs.

Last year, I recently saw my bank person get frustrated with their "new" web interface, and finally give up and walk back over to their 3270 emulator so that they could get "real" work done.  The "new" web interface looked like it was at least 10 years old, the 3270 interface was likely closer to 20-30 years old.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.
Let me ask next question, how to learn to build good integration interfaces?

Comment: That completely depends on your particular scenario.  Enterprise Integration is a profession all its own.  I'd start by reading a lot of books, something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_Integration_Patterns is a good starting place.  Then read about SOA, REST, ESB and any other acronyms you run across.  It's a really big topic, and getting really good at it is a long process.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to provide insight in who knows about what parts of the system. You'll probably want to visualize that in a way that shows the risk to the business. Both for the software itself as for the way it is deployed. That is likely to make a lot of people unhappy, showing that risks have been ignored for far too long. Then you'll need to take a good look at where time is being spend and how to free up capacity to start modernizing. Can you further automate deployment and testing? Can you reduce the number of different technologies used? Standardize on supported version of libraries? Important for the risk to the business is also the amount of change. How stable are the different parts, what is expected to change? And the dependencies, which changes lead to a cascade of changes elsewhere? After you visualize that all, the business needs to decide what risks are acceptable and what needs to be fixed with what priority. That is not a technical responsibility. You need to provide the options with their pros and cons, costs and benefits, but let the business decide on where to spend money